# Wordpress wp_editor bracket bug workaround

Tags: php, wordpress, wysiwyg

I am trying to get the wysiwyg editor to work on a custom options page.
But i am not allowed to use square brackets as editor id.

This is the code i am currently using. 
(Using this as starting point: http://themeshaper.com/2010/06/03/sample-theme-options/ )

```
            <?php

                $content =  $options['sometextarea'];
                $editor_id = 'some_theme_options[sometextarea]';

                $settings =   array(
                    'wpautop' => false, 
                    'media_buttons' => false, 
                    'textarea_name' => $editor_id,
                    'textarea_rows' => get_option('default_post_edit_rows', 10), 
                    'tinymce' => true,
                    'quicktags' => true
                );
                wp_editor( $content , $editor_id, $settings  );

                ?>
```

Could anybody explain to me how to get this working ?
With the current code i am only able to get the wysiwyg editor with quicktags. If i rename $editor_id to plain text i am able to get the full editor, but it will not save.

Comment: Consider using the editor to edit the data, but dump the output to a custom, hidden textarea when saving. That will surely let you bypass the square bracket restriction. A bit dirty, though.

Comment: Sounds like a possible workaround to me. Only thing is i am not sure on how to do this. I get it to work the opposite way, textarea -> wysiwyg.

Comment: I have a gist (https://gist.github.com/RadGH/523bed274f307830752c) with some functions to do this. Or use your own code, which you want `tinyMCE.get(editor_id).getContent()` for the visual editor, and `jQuery('#'+textarea_id).val()` for the text editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got it to work right !

This is how:

```
                <?php

                $content =  $options['sometextarea'];
                $editor_id = 'sometextarea';

                $settings =   array(
                    'wpautop' => false, 
                    'media_buttons' => false, 
                    'textarea_name' => 'mythemename_theme_options[sometextarea]', //You can use brackets here !
                    'textarea_rows' => get_option('default_post_edit_rows', 10), 
                    'tabindex' => '323',
                    'editor_css' => '', 
                    'editor_class' => '',
                    'teeny' => false, 
                    'dfw' => false,
                    'tinymce' => true, 
                    'quicktags' => true 
                );
                wp_editor( $content , $editor_id, $settings  );

                ?>
```

Comment: Do you know if on the client side `tinyMCE.get( "mythemename_theme_options[sometextarea]" ).getContent()` still works too? I thought tinyMCE 4.x wouldn't work with id's containing brackets?

Comment: So the code requires having a different `id` than `name` attribute, correct?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by the `$editor_id` parameter so give it a name without brackets [] so instead of `my_text_area_id_['textarea']` just give it an ordinary ID something like `my-textarea-id` and it should work!

```
wp_editor( 

   string $content, 

    string $editor_id, 

   array $settings = array() 
);
```

Ref :https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_editor/